# Why does the first line throw NullPointerException but second does not?

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception, tostring

The toString method in the following code throws a NullPointerException but the println call after prints null. Why do they not have the same result? THL

```
package exceptionsNullPointer;

public class NPArrays {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] laces = new String[2];

        // this line throws NullPointerException
        System.out.println(laces[1].toString());

        // this line prints null
        System.out.println(laces[1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your last line is never reached.

Comment: @MartinAndersson that's true, but let's assume that the poster refers to the case where one or the other is commented out.

Comment: .. or last line is put in the middle =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `laces[1]` is a perfectly valid reference to a (not yet initialised) member of a `String` array.

When an array of a non-primitive type is created, all of its members default to `null` until they are given an actual value. So referring to `laces[1]` will simply return `null` which is fine.

But your first line tries to call the `toString` method on a null reference. Because a null reference does not point to an actual `String` instance, the only thing that Java can do is throw a `NullPointerException`. You cannot call methods on a `null` reference (or pointer).

Answer (score 3):

`laces[1]` is null because you've not assigned a non-null reference to it yet. This means that in the first case, you can't dereference it to call `toString()`, or you will get a `NullPointerException`.

However, in the second case: quoting the javadoc of [`PrintStream.print(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print-java.lang.String-):

> If the argument is `null` then the string `"null"` is printed.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, laces[1] is `null` and you thus can't call any methods on it.
You can use `Objects.toString` to get a null-safe String representation, eg `System.out.println(Objects.toString(laces[1]));`